# got wrong reult when make division of large double data

Tags: c

There is my code

```
double max = pow(2,1000);
double test = max/10;
```

The result test is a wrong result. I want to know how it happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the precision of float numbers. They are stored in binary format and specifically double can store only 53+1 bits in mantissa.

When you divide such a big number with 10, it will lose some of the bits as it's not possible to express the division precisely in binary number.

Actually it's even impossible to store 1/10 precisely, so here the original power of 2 actually doesn't matter that much.

EDIT: Regarding the other answers - exponent can store 11 bits in double, so  it's able to handle 2^1000.

Comment: It can handle `pow(2, 1000)` but that's kind of misleading, it's unable to handle any number remotely near it as separate different value; the gaps between representable numbers are ~53 bits at that point, so `pow(2, 1000) - pow(2, 946)` is actually the same as just `pow(2, 1000)`. You get _significant_ errors with floating point before you even reach 100 bits; at 1000 bits, it's ballpark numbers on an absurd scale.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: pow(2, 1000) can be represented absolutely precisely in double (and any binary format) as it's power of two. Of course `pow(2, 1000)-pow(2, 946)` is the same as `pow(2, 1000)` as it goes below mantissa precision (difference in exponent is higher than 54 as I mentioned). But basically there is no difference between `pow(2, 1000)/10` and `1/10` as they differ only in exponent. Both suffer from the fact that 1/5 cannot be represented precisely in binary format.

Answer (score 1):

`2^1000` will give an answer bigger then what a double can store.

```
double max=pow(2,1000);
```

This line is leading to overflow.

Comment: Note: [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) can well represent `pow(2,1000)`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the compiler you are using.. As double value will depend on it whether the compiler is 32 bit 64 bit.. if 2^1000 exceeds the size of double than it will overflow

Comment: While the standard would allow a `double` with a `DBL_MAX` of `1e37`, virtually every general purpose system uses IEEE 754 double precision format, which has a limit (just under `1.8e+308`) that would include `pow(2, 1000)` (roughly `1.0715e+301`). The errors will be large in absolute terms on just about any math done with values that large, but it's not actually an overflow.